# References to blank cells become 0's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet in excel where I need to make some references to an area in another spreadsheet. I simply use ='EARTH'!B9:N323, which is an area mixed with some columns of text and others of numerical values. I have one column that shows percentages which can vary between 0-100%, when referencing to the area it it shows all the blank cells from 'EARTH' as 0's, but I just want to keep them blank, any solution?
I cannot of course not just use the advance settings of "Show a zero in cells that have zero value" since some actually have 0 value. Also "" can not work since I also have columns with dates.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I simply change my line to:

```
if(isblank('EARTH'!B9:N323),"",'EARTH'!B9:N323)
```

Comment: The other trick to be aware is that of using function `LEN` to check if the content of a cell has a string length of zero. This is because a formula cannot make a cell empty, instead a formula can (as you have done) give a cell a value `""`, which is a string of length zero. However, a cell containing the  value of `""` returns `FALSE` when used with `ISBLANK` (because it is not actually empty). Using eg `=LEN(A1)=0` returns `TRUE` for both case: (i) when `A1` is empty and (ii) when `A1` contains `""`. In all other cases it returns `FALSE`.